# How to have User Input in a SKScene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm trying to ask the user to input their name in a SKScene but whenever I add a subview it messes up the SKScene and it starts to replay the music and doesnt add the new SKScene that I have the textfield in. Here is my attempt.

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view{
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor lightGrayColor]; // NOTE: temporary background color se
    UILabel *nameField = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 300, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:nameField];
    //[self createMenuTxt];
    [self SetBrickBackground];
}
```

EDIT: I found a related post:
[Adding UITextView to a scene in SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287020/adding-uitextview-to-a-scene-in-spritekit)

Which says that the reason is because the skScene is being presented everytime I add a UITextview. He said to use a guard: if(self.view.scene == nil){}, however, I'm getting that scene is not a property of UIView. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In this case self is the view. So in effect you are saying self.self which obviously does not work.

Change the line `[self.view addSubview:nameField];` to this `[view addSubview:nameField];`